# Amazon SP-API Feed

Tags: c#, amazon, sp-api

Estoy intentando mandar una confirmación de envió a Amazon, para ello se usa la API de Feeds.
Para ello existe una guía en GitHub. [Aqui](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/use-case-guides/feeds-api-use-case-guide/feeds-api-use-case-guide-2020-09-04.md#what-is-the-feeds-api)

El problema es que me quedo en el paso 1.
En este paso tengo que invocar a la API pasándole un parámetro, concretamente `contentType`, además de las cabeceras de autenticación.

He buscado en muchos lados, pero sin éxito, siempre obtengo "invalid input".

> Adjunto código de response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidInput",
      "message": "Invalid Input",
      "details": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

> Además, adjunto parámetros que le paso al request

```
 [0]: {x-amz-access-token=Atza|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
 [1]: {contentType=text/tab-separated-values;charset=UTF-8}
 [2]: {X-Amz-Date=20210610T124106Z}
 [3]: {host=sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com}
 [4]: {Authorization=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxx/20210610/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
 [5]: {Content-type=application/json}
 [6]: {user-agent=My App 1.0 (Language=csharp;Platform=Windows/10)}
```

Lógicamente los datos sensibles no están.

No es un problema de autenticación.

Esta desarrollado en C#.

### **Código para la llamada a la API**

```
        creaAutorizacion();

        string urlApi = "/feeds/2020-09-04/documents";
        restClient = new RestClient(urlApi);
        IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(urlApi, Method.POST);

        restRequest.AddHeader("x-amz-access-token", txtAccessToken.Text);
        //Creo que esto es correcto, pero tampoco estoy seguro... Tampoco veo mucha información al respecto.
        restRequest.AddParameter("contentType", "text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        
        var request = signatureHelper.SignRequest(restRequest, restClient, content_form_urlencoded);

        try
        {
            var result = restClient.Execute(request); //cuando ejecuta me devuelve el "invalid"
        ....
```

Entonces, ahora mi pregunta es: que estoy haciendo mal?, creo que estoy haciendo todo lo que la guía indica.

---

Intentos realizados:

```
Parameter p = new Parameter(
               "contentType",
               "text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8",
                ParameterType.RequestBody
            );
restRequest.Parameters.Add(p);
```

sin exito.

---

Intento realizado

```
restRequest.AddJsonBody(new { contentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8" });
```

Sin exito.

---

Otro intento sin exito, lanzar el request con tipo JSON.

```
var request = signatureHelper.SignRequest(restRequest, restClient, "application/json");
```

sin exito. Invalid input.

Adicionalmente se ha probado agregando el parametro `accept: */*`.
Visto en un foro de Amazon

Comment: agrega los resultado de cada prueba que realizaste.

Comment: ` string urlApi = "/feeds/2020-09-04/documents";` ¿Aquí no debería estar la URL completa incluyendo el dominio?

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso en todos los casos devuelve "Invalid input", lo digo en la explicacion, no obstante lo remarcare.

Comment: @fredyfx correcte, lo monto despues con el codigo C#

Comment: el request es al mismo servidor???

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso a que te refieres? no te comprendo. Todo esta montado en el mismo server.

Comment: Has intentado agregar el accept?                                  
 'restRequest.AddHeader("accept","*/*");

Comment: si con el */*? si.

Comment: De esta manera `restRequest.AddHeader("accept","*/*");` , podrías compartir como lo estás probando con Postman?, o en Postman sigues teniendo el mismo resultado?

Comment: Si lo he probado, con el postman se me hace un mundo, pues la signatrure va en funcion del tiempo.

Comment: Me alegro mucho de que pasaras el paso 1. Yo lo estoy haciendo con Python y me he atascado en el paso 3 sobre subir el documento a la url que te dan en el paso 1. ¿Has logrado pasar tú de ahí? -- @Drageir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por fin el tema esta solucionado, el problema, para quien le interese en el futuro, era la propia API de Amazon y junto con su precaria documentación daban lugar a este error.

No ha hecho falta tocar código, nada. Simplemente Amazon, mediante un caso (un ticket o petición de un usuario, en este caso yo mismo), resolvió, diciendo que en efecto esta errónea la API y pasaban a solucionarlo.

La verdad que saber esto me sorprende, pero he aprendido que por muy grande que sea la empresa, siempre existen los errores.

Para futuras referencias, el código de la pregunta esta ok, se puede usar y es funcional.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas a toda la comunidad.

Posiblemente esto pertenezca a un hilo diferente, pero no lo he encontrado.

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en C# por mi para conectar con Amazon MWS con sus librerías (dll) correspondientes para realizar las distintas operaciones que necesito.

Ahora estoy empezando con la migración a SP-API y encuentro algún proyecto de ejemplo pero no consigo entender como realiza las operaciones (no veo la dll que hay que usar y tampoco veo que lo hagan en C#, lo que he encontrado es java o web (mediante HTTP, etc..)

Todo esto me hace preguntarme ¿tengo que desarrollarlo en otro lenguaje que no sea C#?

La verdad es que ando un poco perdido con esta migración, por que además la documentación que aporta Amazon es poco clarificante.

Si alguien puede arrojarme luz a mis dudas le estaré muy agradecido.

Comment: vamos al chat, abro uno, hablamos alli.

Answer (score -1):

Por lo que leo en la [documentación](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html) el envió de información para Amazon el envio es en xml por lo que entiendo que si el content type se lo envias como JSON no te lo tolerara.
Cuando he visto tu prueba con xml veo que lo insertar el content type con `.AddJsonBody(` en  `restRequest.AddJsonBody(new { contentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8" });` por lo que entiendo que lo metere pero el body no es correcto retornándote que los parámetros de entrada no son correctos.
He buscado un ejemplo para que puedas probar como seria añadir de esta forma

```
string nextID = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><ServiceRequest> <filters> <Criteria field = \"id\" operator=\"GREATER\"> 13782472 </Criteria></filters></ServiceRequest>"; 

request.AddHeader("X-Requested-With", "RestSharp");

request.AddParameter("text/xml", nextID, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Te dejo un link que parece interesante para que puedas llamas a AWS seguramente puedas adaptar el [ejemeplo](https://www.example-code.com/csharp/mws_submitfeed.asp)

Una prueba rápida si el xml de AWS no requiere mucho y no quieres perder mucho tiempo seria probar a parsear de json a xml `XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);` de esta forma podras reutilizar el codigo que tienes o si tienes un objeto para serializar a xml usaria este `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());`

Comment: Gracias, por tu respuesta, lamentablemente no es el sitio correcto, esa API MWS, ya no es utilizable, en la pregunta esta el link a la documentación, que es de SP-API (Seller partner API). Veras que la cosa cambia y bastante.

Comment: Ya no es utilizable por que va a dejar de usarse, y estan migrando todo a MWS a SP-API

Comment: @Srsole no se si te servirá pero he encontrado esta serie de videos que te pueden ayudar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mczbPja_OLs

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, lamentablemente tambien lo habia visto, pero no aporta nada nuevo. Ten encuenta que llevo cerca de un mes con esto, y todo el tema de videos y tal lo tengo muy visto.